# The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild-task, msbuildcommunitytasks

In VS2019, I have MVC dotnet framework project and while doing dotnet build got the issue

```
error MSB4801: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild
error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll".
```

Comment: ref: https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/51 , adding the target does not solve the problem, actually the project is not ref pacakges.config at all and here need to change a whole csproj file how to do it

Answer (score -1):

Comment this lines on your **csproj**:

```
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <EnvVarSet VarName="DOTNET_HOST_PATH" VarValue="dotnet" />
</Target>
```

```
<!-- <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
        <EnvVarSet VarName="DOTNET_HOST_PATH" VarValue="dotnet" />
    </Target> -->
```

Comment: This does not exist in my case...

Comment: Care to explain why?